# Undefined index error when using session variables

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am working on a project where i already built signup, login, profile update forms.

Am using sessions to get currently logged in user info to be able to update his profile using profile update form. Now problem is that when i am assigning those session variables to update form. I get the following error.

This is my authController.php where all the processing of php is coded.

```
session_start();
$username = "";
$gender = "";
$dob = "";
$country = "";
$state = "";

  if (isset($_POST['update-btn'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $errors['username'] = 'Username required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['gender'])) {
        $errors['gender'] = 'Gender required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['dd'])) {
        $errors['dd'] = 'Day required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['mm'])) {
        $errors['mm'] = 'Month required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['yyyy'])) {
        $errors['yyyy'] = 'Year required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['country'])) {
        $errors['country'] = 'Country required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['state'])) {
        $errors['state'] = 'State required';
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $dob = $_POST['yyyy']."/". $_POST['mm']."/".$_POST['dd'];   
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];

        if (count($errors) === 0) {
        $query = "UPDATE users SET username=?, gender=?, dob=?, country=?, state=? WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $username, $gender, $dob, $country, $state);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();

            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['gender'] = $gender;
            $_SESSION['dob'] = $dob;
            $_SESSION['country'] = $country;
            $_SESSION['state'] = $state;
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Your profile is updated!';
            $_SESSION['type'] = 'alert-success';
            header('location: updateprofileform.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Database error: Could not update user";
        }
    }
```

This is profile page.php just a small part of code where the error is pointed

```
<?php
require_once 'controllers/authController.php';

// If the session variable is empty, this  
// means the user is yet to login 
// User will be sent to 'login.php' page 
// to allow the user to login 
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { 
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You have to log in first"; 
    header('location: login.php'); 
} 

?>

      <p class="user-info">
        <b><span style="color:tomato;">Username : </span><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></b>
        <br>
        <b><span style="color:tomato;">Gender : </span><?php echo $_SESSION['gender']; ?></b>
        <br>
        <b><span style="color:tomato;">DOB : </span><?php echo $_SESSION['dob']; ?></b>
        <br>
        <b><span style="color:tomato;">Country : </span><?php echo $_SESSION['country']; ?></b>
        <br>
        <b><span style="color:tomato;">State : </span><?php echo $_SESSION['state']; ?></b>
      </p>
```

It shows undefined index error for gender,dob,country,state where i want to display the values using session variables

More INFO :

I have already started session in authController.php and linked it to update form using require once

Previously when i was working on this there was no problem and now whenever i open the profile page in browser it shows following error. When i submit the form with details the error disappears. But if i use this code on actual server the error displays when user first go to profile page i don't want that to be happen.

I know that if value is not assigned to the variable it shows this error but i have assigned the value
i don't know where am i going wrong

Can anyone help me with this

Thank you

Comment: i just used session_start() only once in authController.php and haven't used anywhere again

Comment: you've accessed this page, not as a POST, or not containing those POST variables.

Comment: Have you actually submitted the form successfully in order to set the $_SESSION variables

Comment: When first time i assigned the values it worked perfectly fine and afterwards when i close the browser and again open the profilepage where the values should be visible it shows undefined index error

Comment: After `header('location: login.php'); `, you should add a `die()`

Comment: @Ali khalili  I tried using die() had no effect

Comment: When am i am submitting the form second time the error disappears but what i want is the error shoudn't be displayed when first time i open the profile page

Comment: Did you try to var_dump your session to see which variables are there in *page.php*?

Comment: yeah i used var_dump it shows all the values with session variables. My problem is that why first timw when i load the page its shows undefined error